# Wrapper re-size

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper surrounding a header with content inside as well as a container with content inside.  The wrapper is really on there to keep everything positioned to each other accordingly within the confines I set, as well as to center everything.  I have my container to automatically re-size according to the content that goes inside of it, this works without issue.  However, the wrapper around the header and the container won't follow the same rule and ends up taking a height of 1px it seems.  Please note: the code below will show the wrapper outlined by a dashed white border up at the top, it should instead wrap around everything it contains.

[Here's the code to the website on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w5yT7/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I feel as though I closed all of my floats, I don't see why the height: auto; on wrapper won't work, but maybe there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: auto` on `#wrapper` isn't working because virtually every element inside it has `position: absolute`.

What does `position: absolute` do? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

> In the absolute positioning model, a
>   box is explicitly offset with respect
>   to its containing block. **It is
>   removed from the normal flow entirely
>   (it has no impact on later
>   siblings).** An absolutely positioned
>   box establishes a new containing block
>   for normal flow children and
>   absolutely (but not fixed) positioned
>   descendants. **However, the contents
>   of an absolutely positioned element do
>   not flow around any other boxes.**

The choices to fix your problem:

- Give `#wrapper` an explicit `height` - but that won't work if you don't know the `height` beforehand.
- As @jeroen said: use JavaScript to set the `height` of `#wrapper`.
- **What you should *really* do is completely redo your CSS:**
  `position: absolute` *is not* how you should position every element on the page. You should use `float`s instead.

For a comparison of using `position: absolute` vs `float`s, see:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/

Comment: I ended up making my container AND my header a position of relative, even though some of the elements inside of the header are absolute.  The wrapper looked to the child elements (header and container) directly inside of it, NOT to all the elements inside of each of them as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using absolute positioning for the contents of the wrapper, `#container` and that takes it completely out of the document flow. The same applies to the contents of your header.

The only way to get your wrapper to wrap, is using javascript to calculate and set the height manually.